# Python Flask_MYSQLDB problems

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python, flask-login

**Hi**

I have been following a step by step on how to make a [login system with python](https://codeshack.io/login-system-python-flask-mysql/), with flask-mysqldb. I'm trying to run the python script, but i end up getting a error message that i don't understand so much of.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re

app = flask(__name__)
```

When I'm trying to run the script, on the localhost page it also shows a [error](https://pastebin.com/aTece8bX), I have copyed and pasted te error in pastebin. When I try to install the flask_mysqldb i get a error in my cmd. [Here is what my cmd says](https://pastebin.com/5qAss1Jm).

I have google with parts of the error, trying to find some information about what the problem can be. And tryed to pip install a lot for things that some people have said that can work, without any luck. And can't figure out how to get this to work.

I also tryed to install Anaconda terminal to run the command in there for installing flask_mysqldb, but no luck. Tryed to uninstall and reinstall everything, but nothing changed the error i get.

Comment: Did you run pip install flask-mysqldb?

Comment: Yes. And tryed to run "pip install flask_mysqldb" also. Due to the name in the code is with underline.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'
```

indicates that the module has not been installed or installed in a wrong environment. 
Install it using:

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

Comment: if u look at my cmd code you will se that i have tryed that, but it shows a error there to...

Comment: That is correct. The pip packages install correctly here. May I suggest that you start over again by creating a new virtual environment by using "python -m venv .env"? That way you can ensure you do not have conflicting packages.

Comment: I have tryed that, but I will try agien.

Comment: here i have tryed to install the flask-mysqldb agian [link](https://pastebin.com/Xn54iT8P)

Comment: I have been able to fully recreate your code here, so after some investigation I can see a lot of people with failed installations on 32 bit machines. Are you running natively on 32 bit or did you just download Python for 32 bit?

Comment: Also keep in mind your code should read app = Flask(__name__)
 and  not app = flask(__name__)

Comment: I believe it is a 64 bit. When I went to download python I clicked on the one that showed up on the download page.  I will change that in my code and see if it will run. I will get back to you.

Comment: I can see from your logs you that you are using Python for Windows 32. Uninstall it and try to install Python for Win 64 and and try again.

Comment: Well, now i have uninstalled everything, and during reinstalling i have had some issues. I will come back to you when i get everything up and running agien.

Comment: I got it to stop showing error's by starting fresh. Now it only shows 404 -page not found. So it means that its running but cant find the homepage(index) so now i will go over the tutorial agien to see if i got some wrong lines of code. Thanks for you help! :)

Comment: Very welcome. Given that your webserver is running (You should see a message like "Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/") you need to define a route to actually see a web page. Until then Flask doesn't know what to show.  So in your example that is: @app.route('/pythonlogin/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return render_template('index.html', msg='')
Finally, if you think you got the help you needed, consider accepting my post as answer. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

The stack from from the error

```
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\pythonlogin\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'
```

is indicating that Python 3.7 in involved.

In this case, using `pip` to install `flask_mysqldb` will lead to grief. Use `pip3` instead. E.g.,

```
pip3 install flask_mysqldb
```